# Change Path Fill inside radio button WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, radio-button, styles, togglebutton

I read on internet that to make a custom style of radio button you need to create a toggle button style.

So here my style :

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MainOrangeBrush}" />
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource MainDarkerGrayBrush}" />
   <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource MainDarkerGrayBrush}" />
   <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
   <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Border
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
               <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </Border>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
   <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource MainDarkerGrayBrush}" />
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MainWhiteBrush}" />
         <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource MainOrangeBrush}" />
      </Trigger>
      <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource MainOrangeBrush}" />
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MainWhiteBrush}" />
         <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource MainDarkerGrayBrush}" />
      </Trigger>
      <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource MainOrangeBrush}" />
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MainWhiteBrush}" />
         <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource MainOrangeBrush}" />
      </Trigger>
      <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource MainDarkerGrayBrush}" />
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisableGrayBrush}" />
         <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource MainWhiteBrush}" />
      </Trigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate>
            <ToggleButton Content="{Binding Path=(Content), RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type RadioButton}}}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=(IsChecked), RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type RadioButton}}}" />
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

I still don't fully understand `ContentTemplate` and `ContentPresenter`. I understand that the content presenter is for everything inside the UI element.

So my problem is that I want to set the fill the same color as the foreground inside the toggle button:

```
<RadioButton
   x:Name="Btn"
   Width="40"
   Height="40"
   HorizontalAlignment="Right"
   IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"
   ToolTip="Btn">
   <Path
      Width="30"
      Margin="2"
      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
      VerticalAlignment="Center"
      Data="F1 M 19.135,13.006 L 12.740,13.006 L 17.243,0.000 L 0.000,17.142 L 6.397,17.142 L 1.480,30.148 L 19.135,13.006 Z"
      Fill="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ToggleButton}}}"
      Stretch="Uniform" />
</RadioButton>
```

This line does not work :

```
Fill="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ToggleButton}}}"
```

Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I read on internet that to make a custom style of radio button you need to create a toggle button style.

No. You have to create a style for the type `RadioButton`. The `RelativeSource` binding does not work, because it does not search for ancestors within the control template and will therefore not find the `ToggleButton`.

In order to solve your issue, you should create an appropriate style for `RadioButton`. It is not necessary to use a toggle button in it, but even if you would, the triggers would be defined in the control template, too. Moreover, the style for the `ToggleButton` as you have defined it is *implicit* (without an `x:Key`), which causes it to be applied to every toggle button in scope, not just the `RadioButton` and that is not what you want.

I have created a sample style that might look similar to what your are trying to do.

```
<Style x:Key="FocusVisual1">
   <Setter Property="Control.Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate>
            <Rectangle Margin="2" StrokeDashArray="1 2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="OptionMarkFocusVisual1">
   <Setter Property="Control.Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate>
            <Rectangle Margin="14,0,0,0" StrokeDashArray="1 2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
   <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual1}"/>
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MainOrangeBrush}" />
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource MainDarkerGrayBrush}" />
   <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource MainDarkerGrayBrush}" />
   <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
   <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
   <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
   <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
            <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
               <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
               </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <Border x:Name="radioButtonBorder" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="1,1,2,1" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                  <Grid x:Name="markGrid" Margin="2">
                     <Path x:Name="optionMark"
                                 MinHeight="6"
                                 MinWidth="6"
                                 Margin="2"
                                 Opacity="0"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                 Data="F1 M 19.135,13.006 L 12.740,13.006 L 17.243,0.000 L 0.000,17.142 L 6.397,17.142 L 1.480,30.148 L 19.135,13.006 Z"
                                 Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                 Stretch="Uniform" />
                  </Grid>
               </Border>
               <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Grid.Column="1" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               <Trigger Property="HasContent" Value="true">
                  <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource OptionMarkFocusVisual1}"/>
                  <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,-1,0,0"/>
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                  <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="radioButtonBorder" Value="{StaticResource MainWhiteBrush}"/>
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="radioButtonBorder" Value="{StaticResource MainOrangeBrush}"/>
                  <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="{StaticResource MainDarkerGrayBrush}"/>
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                  <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="radioButtonBorder" Value="{StaticResource DisableGrayBrush}"/>
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="radioButtonBorder" Value="{StaticResource MainWhiteBrush}"/>
                  <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="{StaticResource MainDarkerGrayBrush}"/>
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                  <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="radioButtonBorder" Value="{StaticResource MainWhiteBrush}"/>
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="radioButtonBorder" Value="{StaticResource MainDarkerGrayBrush}"/>
                  <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="{StaticResource MainOrangeBrush}"/>
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                  <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="optionMark" Value="1"/>
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
                  <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="optionMark" Value="0.56"/>
               </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

The result looks like below. It is still a radio button, but with your custom `Path` as option mark and your custom colors applied to the respective states.

[image: Radio Button Sample]

In this example, the `Path` is embedded in the control template and the `Content`, here the text *Test* is still applied. You can of course further customize the template so that it fits your requirements.

If you want the `Content` and the option mark to be customizable without creating a different style, you will have to create a custom radio button control derived from `RadioButton` and expose a dependency property to specify the option mark content. Then you can bind it in the control template, but that is another question.